# AngularJS: Assign NgModel dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, dynamic, angular-ngmodel

I've got a controller in which I've got an array called `fields`. This array has the following structure (with some data as an example):

```
[
    {
        "name": "Demarcación",
        "type": "multiple",
        "scope": "restricted",
        "icon": "location-arrow",
        "order": 1,
        "id": 1,
        "possible_values": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "field_id": 1,
                "name": "Demarcación 1"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "field_id": 1,
                "name": "Demarcación 2"
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "field_id": 1,
                "name": "Demarcación 3"
            }
        ],
        "values": [
            {
                "id": 3,
                "value": "Demarcación 3"
            }
        ]
    },
    ...
]
```

Then, I want to create a form where **the inputs are consctructed dynamically** depending on the fields' `type` and `scope`. So, if the `scope` equals `free`, for example, then a `textarea` is added. Otherwise, an `input text` is added.

I need to **perform some Javascript initialization depending on the field** type, too, so - for example - if the `scope` is restricted I need to initialize a JQuery plugin on that input.

I've tried to set a function where I construct the HTML string and then print it in a `ngRepeat`, but I get the text as plain text (even using `$sce.trustAsHtml()`), without luck.

### The question

Is there any way that I can write dynamically the inputs / html to add to document - and process some Javascript logic - and to which I can attach dynamically some AngularJS properties (like `ngModel` so its values get data-binded with the object)?

*The inputs would be inside an ngRepeat directive, so I have access to the objects iterated and I can pass them as variables into a function.*

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the $compile service

[Angular Documentation for $compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)

```
$compile(element.contents())(scope);
```

[Example in plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/vn82TZnFCl4oJPUwq4ux?p=preview)

Comment: I think it's what I needed! I've tested it and it seems to work. The only thing I'm worried about is performance. The fact that it's watching explicitly - specified by me - so many properties won't slow down performance? Thank you for your answer and time!

Comment: In fact, after a while testing, it gets laggy whenever I try to type anything into any of the inputs... I think it's a performance issue regarding the `$watch` code. If you have any confirmation (or not) about the performance issue, I'd appreciate you to share it! Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

That's a good start. That might be a good idea to go for a directive.
Also, i think there are so form generators that handle this type of work: http://schemaform.io/

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.fields = window.fields;
    $scope.fieldInit = function(field){
      //console.log('things and stuff: ' + JSON.stringify(field));
     }
});

window.fields = [
    {
        "name": "field 1",
        "type": "text",
        "scope": "restricted",
        "icon": "location-arrow",
        "order": 1,
        "id": 1,
        "possible_values": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "field_id": 1,
                "name": "Demarcación 1"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "field_id": 1,
                "name": "Demarcación 2"
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "field_id": 1,
                "name": "Demarcación 3"
            }
        ],
        "values": [
            {
                "id": 3,
                "value": "Demarcación 3"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "field 2",
        "type": "multiple",
        "scope": "restricted",
        "icon": "location-arrow",
        "order": 1,
        "id": 2,
        "possible": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "field_id": 1,
                "name": "Demarcación 1"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "field_id": 1,
                "name": "Demarcación 2"
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "field_id": 1,
                "name": "Demarcación 3"
            }
        ],
        "values": [
            {
                "id": 3,
                "value": "Demarcación 3"
            }
        ]
    }
 
]
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
 

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="field in fields" ng-init="fieldInit(field)">
  {{field.name}}
    <input ng-model="field.model" ng-if="field.type != 'multiple'" type="{{field.type}}"/>
    <select ng-model="field.model" ng-if="field.type == 'multiple'" 
    ng-options="val.name for val in field.possible" />
  <div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I had thought of a directive, too, but I preferred to give it a try from a more scalable way! Thanks for your answer and time!

Comment: Hope you'll be able to handle all your rules by going like that. Unfortunatly this might looks ugly at some point. :(  That's why a directive would be great. Good luck.